# Good free editors for non-European languages?

Tags: editors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Editors supporting unicode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/editors-supporting-unicode)

WinEdt is a quite good <s>free</s> editor which I am using. Motivated by the comments to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23008/5590), I would like to raise the question here:

> Is there a good editor for non-European languages? (Free editor is preferable.)

Comment: Take a look at for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/editors-supporting-unicode, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16512/cjk-friendly-ubuntu-editor-or-ide-for-xelatex

Comment: Winedt is not free.

Comment: @Ulrike: Ah, I found that. :)

Comment: i believe the mule flavor of emacs can handle just about anything, provided you've got the appropriate fonts, but i've never used it for anything non-european.  emacs is rather an undertaking to learn, but i've found it was worth the effort.