# Install MiKTeX on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: miktex, installing, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 15.04. Where can I get the Miktex for this platform ?. I could not find in any Ubuntu software sources.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/download) no more is available for Linux distros, MiKTeX is a LaTeX distro for windows users _only_ . The simple and quick way to install TeX/LaTeX on Ubuntu 15.04 is use TeXLive 2014 in your ubuntu distro (2014.20141024-2ubuntu1). To  install full texlive distro if space is not a constraint run in your Terminal `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`

Comment: Please let us know if your Q is a Possible Duplicate of [I want to start using LaTeX on Ubuntu. Where do I start?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225/15717).

Comment: I am going to try with Texmaker, and TeXstudio. Which one is better to write a "Thesis"?, my thesis includes a lengthy and a bigger physics equations and HD images too.

Comment: @RameshManda The choice of the editor depends on your needs and so everyone would give you a subjective opinion. 
If you do not like to see your thesis like writing a program (as it's my case ) I would suggest LyX, which is a "word environment with the power of latex". If you want to have full control of your document, then both texstudio and texmaker are pretty good options